# List add function does not operate properly?

Tags: java, list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<item> l = new ArrayList<item>();
    List<Integer> ll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        l.add(new item(i,i));
        ll.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(l.get(4).getWeight());
    System.out.println(ll.get(4));
}

public class item {
    private static int value;
    private static int weight;
    public item(int val, int w) {
        setValue(val);
        setWeight(w);
    }
    public static int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public static void setValue(int value) {
        item.value = value;
    }
    public static int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public static void setWeight(int weight) {
        item.weight = weight;
    }
```

}

This is my code, and then item is class take two paratemers. But when I add the item into list, the elelments in list have same value(in this case it is 9). For Integer, there is no problem. I think I miss some critical parts of java feature.

Any help appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You are passing `i` correctly to your `item` constructor. You then imply that `item#getWeight()` is not returning the correct value. Clearly, the problem is in `item`, but for some unknown reason, you have left `item`s code out of your question. (As an aside, name your classes whatever you want, but it is common practice to start class names in Java with capital letters; even SO's syntax highlighter doesn't like lowercase class names.)

Comment: @JasonC I have put the class code

Comment: Nothing in `item` needs to be static. Once you fix that, change `item.value` to `this.value` and same for weight.

Answer (score 10):

All of your methods and members of `item` are `static`. That is, they belong to the `item` *class*, rather than a specific instance of that class. The `static` members are shared among every instance of the class, and so every new `item` you create is using the same set of data. You will want to make them not be `static`.

Check out the following official tutorials for more info, they are concise and well-written and will help you:

- Non-static, member variables: [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)
- Non-static, methods: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)
- `static` class members: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Once you have done this, as [Takendarkk astutely points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115415/list-add-function-does-not-operate-properly/27115466#comment42733631_27115415), be sure to use `this.value = ...` instead of `item.value = ...` (no longer valid) or `value = ...` (uses local scope `value` instead of member).